# Olympiad inequality

Tags: inequality, contest-math, fractions, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Let $a,b,c,d \in [0,1]$.
>   Prove 
>   $$ \frac {a}{1+b}+\frac{b}{1+c}+\frac{c}{1+d}+\frac{d}{1+a}+abcd\le3$$

Hi. Im a school student so ive been unable to look for ways to apply this problem. I attempted to use AM-GN on 1+a etc but the bound $2\sqrt{a}$ was too large and was easily larger than 3. Thus id like some help solving this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $a,b,c,d \in [0,1]$, let
$$
f(a,b,c,d)
=
\frac{a}{1+b}
+
\frac{b}{1+c}
+
\frac{c}{1+d}
+
\frac{d}{1+a}
+
abcd
$$
The goal is to prove $f(a,b,c,d) \le 3$, for all $a,b,c,d \in [0,1]$.

For fixed $b,c,d \in [0,1]$, let $g(a) = f(a,b,c,d)$.

Then 
$$g''(a) = \frac{2d}{(a+1)^3}$$
hence $g''(a) \ge 0$, for all $a \in [0,1]$.

It follows that $g$ is convex on $[0,1]$, hence the maximum value of $g$ on $[0,1]$ is achieved at one of the endpoints.

Thus, for fixed $b,c,d$, the function $f(a,b,c,d)$ is maximized at $a=0$ or $a=1$.

The same reasoning applies to each of the variables $b,c,d$, with the other $3$ variables held fixed.

Thus, to prove $f(a,b,c,d) \le 3$, for all $a,b,c,d \in [0,1]$, it suffices to verify that $f(a,b,c,d) \le 3$, for all $a,b,c,d \in \{0,1\}$.

If any of $a,b,c,d$ is zero, the expression 
$$
\frac{a}{1+b}
+
\frac{b}{1+c}
+
\frac{c}{1+d}
+
\frac{d}{1+a}
+
abcd
$$
reduces to a sum of $3$ fractions, each of which is at most $1$, hence the sum is at most $3$.

If $a,b,c,d$ are all equal to $1$, the expression 
$$
\frac{a}{1+b}
+
\frac{b}{1+c}
+
\frac{c}{1+d}
+
\frac{d}{1+a}
+
abcd
$$
evaluates to exactly $3$.

Thus, the claimed inequality is proved.

Comment: Answering a deleted comment . . .
$$$$Let $M=\max(g(0),g(1))$. Let $t \in [0,1]$. Then since $g$ is convex on $[0,1]$,
$$g(t) \le (1-t)g(0) + tg(1) \le (1-t)M + tM = M$$
hence the maximum value of $g(t)$ on $[0,1]$ is achieved at $t=0$ or $t=1$.

Comment: Superb. You explained so well that even a layman like me could understand. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

We need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a}{1+b}-a\right)+abcd\leq3-a-b-c-d$$ or
$$3-a-b-c-d+\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{1+b}\geq abcd.$$
Now, by C-S and the given condition $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{1+b}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{abcd}{cd+bcd}\geq\frac{16abcd}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(cd+bcd)}\geq\frac{16abcd}{8}=2abcd.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$3-a-b-c-d+abcd\geq0,$$ which is a linear inequality of all variables.

Thus, $$\min_{\{a,b,c,d\}\subset[0,1]}(3-a-b-c-d+abcd)=\min_{\{a,b,c,d\}\subset\{0,1\}}(3-a-b-c-d+abcd)=0$$ and we are done!

Comment: What is C-S? I dont get the solution.

Comment: @Mojimoji It's Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: how did you apply cauchy schwarz

Comment: @Mojimoji It's $\frac{1^2}{x}+\frac{1^2}{y}+\frac{1^2}{z}+\frac{1^2}{t}\geq\frac{(1+1+1+1)^2}{x+y=z+t}=\frac{16}{x+y+z+t}$ for positives $x$, $y$, $z$ and $t$.

Comment: ahh i see thanks

Comment: In your last equation, I think you mean for the 2nd conditional to be $\{ a, b, c, d, \} \in \{ 0, 1 \} $ (with an abuse of notation).

Comment: @Calvin Lin It's a standard notation. $1\in\{0,1\}$, but $\{1\}\subset\{0,1\}$. In my post it means $a\in\{0,1\}$, $b\in\{0,1\}$, $c\in\{0,1\}$ and $d\in\{0,1\}$. All this we can write like $\{a,b,c,d\}\subset\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Oh, perfect. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome!